# Exclude part of a string when testing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I take a test statement that tests for two equal strings, such as, `if @current_lesson.code == @current_course.answer`, and exclude some parts of the answer. So, if I want to make the user write a `<p>` tag with anything in it, how would I make it correct, as long as they have the `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Regexp to check if you have a `<p>` tag with text inside the string. If you use Rspec, i'd use the `matches` matcher.

The code would be something like this:

```
expect(@current_lesson.code).to match(/\<p\>.+\<\/p\>/)
```

Didnt check the regexp, it is just to prove a point :).

Comment: But how would I use it with the @current_course.answer ?

Comment: It depends on how you define a "correct answer". If you want the user to be 100% correct, use `include?` or `expect(@current_lesson.code).to match(@current_course.answer)`. If you want to be more flexible, it gets trickier with `@current_course.answer` being dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "*include*" method for string object:

Example :

```
if @current_course.answer.include? @current_lesson.code
  #Your code logic here
end
```

Comment: Very strict mode: that would only work if the `current_lesson` is **exactly** the same as the answer...